# React Native DrawerNavigator in Stack navigator is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, drawer, stack-navigator

I have trouble using the react-navigation like stack navigation with drawer navigation

```js
const Drawerstack = DrawerNavigator({
 updatesegregation : { screen: UpdateSegregation },
  listoffers : { screen: ListOffers },
  mypurse : { screen: MyPurse },
  myoffers : { screen: MyOffers },
  segregationhistory : { screen: SegregationHistory },
  ranking : { screen: Ranking },
  updates : { screen: Blogs },
  contactus : { screen: ContactUs },
  termsandconditions : { screen: TermsAndConditions },
  instruction : { screen: Instructions },
  profile : { screen: Profile },
  segregationtips : { screen: SegregationTips },
  faqs : {screen: Faqs },
},{
 contentComponent: NavigationDrawer,
})

const Index = StackNavigator({
  authcheck : { screen: AuthCheck },
  login: { screen: Login },
  registration : { screen: Registration },
  profileedit : { screen: ProfileEdit },
  socialregistration : { screen: SocialRegistration },
  forgotpassword : { screen: ForgotPassword },
  drawerstack: { screen: Drawerstack },
},
 {
    headerMode: 'none'
});

export default Index;
```

the root page is authcheck which checks the access token and return the user.

```js
fetch(url.main + 'version' + url.transform, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        } 
 }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
   //alert(JSON.stringify(responseData))
   if(responseData.version[0].version_code == Version){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('User').then((value) => {
     //alert(JSON.parse(value));
     var tmpValue = JSON.parse(value);
     if (tmpValue !== null) {
     
      this.props.navigation.navigate("updatesegregation");
     }else{
      this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
     }
    })
   }else{
    this.PopupDialog.show();
   }
  })
```

But when there is access token availabe then it didn't show any error an also it didn't navigate to the requested page.

This navigation is not redirecting me to the page i want from the DrawerNavigator...

if anyone knows please help...

Comment: Please show full code `authcheck`

Comment: @AhsanAli yes you check full code above

Comment: where are you calling `fetch`, in `constructor`?

Comment: I am calling fetch function in componentWillMount () function @AhsanAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to reference

> this.prop

create a global function

```
 onAuthentication = (screenName) =>{

this.props.navigation.navigate(screenName)

};
```

and then call this function inside ur fetch function like

```
this.onAuthentication('updatesegregation') or this.onAuthentication('login')
```

Comment: Hello, 

I have tried your way but when i use update segregation in this function then nothing happens and when i use login then it redirects me to login but when the user token presents then i have to redirect it to update segregation...

Comment: without your answer the navigation run when i put login in it...
but when the page from the drawer navigator then it didn't redirect...
my question is about the Drawer navigation is not working....
the screens in drawer navigator it didn't redirect to that screens...